# git commit command execute as docker command (?!)

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

Try to commit changes, but get an error by docker

```
git commit -m "some"
no such service: php
```

I am not in docker container, try to use github desktop - same issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is not a native `git` message. Check if you have any hooks activated in your repo (`ls .git/hooks`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pre-commit hook in the repository.

```
git commit --no-verify
```

allows to avoid it once. Or you can remove it completely from `.git/hooks`. Or you can install dependencies for the hook; `php` seems to be the 1st such dependency.